# Run a python script before loading webpage from javascript/html

Tags: javascript, python, csv, html

I have an index.html which reads a csv file and displays it on a webpage using `Javascript DataTables`. It is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>CSV to HTML Table</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <h2>CSV to HTML Table</h2>



      <div id='table-container'></div>

    </div><!-- /.container -->



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/csv_to_html_table.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      function format_link(link){
        if (link)
          return "<a href='" + link + "' target='_blank'>" + link + "</a>";
        else
          return "";
      }
      CsvToHtmlTable.init({
        csv_path: 'data/fatty_acid_profiles.csv',
        element: 'table-container', 
        allow_download: true,
        csv_options: {separator: ','},
        datatables_options: {"paging": false},
        custom_formatting: [[4, format_link]]
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have this running on an `ec2` instance. I want that when this url is opened, before loading the page, first a python script called `computation.py` should be run that creates the above `data/fatty_acid_profiles.csv` file and then the page should load. How do I do I enable running the python script before loading the page?

Comment: How are you serving your html?

Comment: I don't know how else you would do it without actually setting up a server and using a frame work like flask, and make a handler inside of computation.py that gets called when you click on the link. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/

Comment: @user3080953 I wrote I'm running it on AWS ec2, so Apache Web Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple flask app to serve the HTML file, refer [Flask Documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/). In the index route, you can call computation.py's function to generate the required CSV file and then return the HTML page.